# Should diff3 be default conflictstyle on git?

Tags: git, git-diff, diff3

Recently I enabled diff3 and it's much easier to resolve conflict now.

Previously in some cases I had to check the log to see why people did this and that to do the merge. But with diff3 the information is displayed all in one place

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
THIS IS USEFUL
||||||| merged common ancestors
This is useful
=======
This is really useful
>>>>>>> c2392943.....
```

From that we can easily see that the result should be "THIS IS REALLY USEFUL"

I wonder if there is any downside to diff3? Why it is not the default behavior of git?

Comment: I think it should absolutely be the default.  Great and highly illustrative example, by the way.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

For other readers (and [from this article](http://psung.blogspot.fr/2011/02/reducing-merge-headaches-git-meets.html)):

> git has an option to display merge conflicts in `diff3` format (by default it only displays the two files to be merged). You can enable it like so:

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

> There's really no reason you shouldn't enable the diff3 style, because you frequently need the ancestor to determine what the correct merge is.

This was introduced [fairly early (2008)](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=122005703817173&w=2), and I suppose it isn't the default, because a default Unix `diff` isn't display as a 3-way diff.

With [Git 2.35, you also have **`zdiff3`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70387424/6309) ("**zealous diff3**").

---

As mentioned [in this thread](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=132928201919888&w=2), if you want to run this command without setting the config, so that you can switch between normal diffs and diff3s easily, this is possible in one specific case:

> If a conflict is marked in the index (i.e., the state you are in after a conflicted merge, but before you mark a path as resolved), you can do:
>
> ```
> git checkout --conflict=diff3 <path...>
> ```
>
> Note that that is actually checking out the index contents into the working tree, so any edits you may have made to the conflicted working tree copy will be overwritten.

---

Note that the `|||||| merged common ancestors` will evolve with git 2.24 (Q4 2019)

See [commit b657047](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6570477193b8cf75ce625b8d540e28f71ece3fe) (07 Oct 2019), [commit 8e4ec33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e4ec3376e9d73bd471336cc7c11b35f5bc5dc87) (01 Oct 2019), and [commit 4615a8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4615a8cb5b3a8d4959c30338925b1fa3b948ae52), [commit 45ef16f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45ef16f77ae5a14aa751d03c9c9fc2fa91804425), [commit f3081da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3081dae014e08ece75cfb28a9844beb01b6d9f2), [commit 5bf7e57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bf7e5779ec6d5293b3135554d49e6fcee88d399), [commit e95e481](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e95e481f9e6e4dfe62380ccc8a47acf446403a94), [commit a779fb8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a779fb829bf6160cb519500ac1e15d8ab8a247a4), [commit 8599ab4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8599ab4574ce3a8b2fc894c7cfdac8fd61450b7b), [commit 7c0a6c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c0a6c8e477bd9009001590f49274e892e92fce8), [commit c749ab1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c749ab1da812cdb1263f868c63fe1808a12dcff2), [commit bab5687](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bab56877e04efcf1bf9154398131dd57d73725d4), [commit ff1bfa2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff1bfa2cd5693900a84750dc47cda3cee3cf6ba7), [commit 4d7101e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d7101e25cfd5fba24ddc310f10c3962edba8b4d), [commit 724dd76](https://github.com/git/git/commit/724dd767b245db588840d7e9dbd46687ee84020b), [commit 345480d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/345480d1ed462135d98e99cb5b5a426da27257c8), [commit b4db8a2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4db8a2b768742f4f43d4a6cdb1db39c2ffc9f7f), [commit 98a1d3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98a1d3d88895a1cbc01b88627776bb4e2bfd6b84), [commit 9822175](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9822175d2b349be1ed7a704d3a56dc912f5a7510), [commit 10f751c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10f751c06bb3dbc2afed0e80ecfbd6242e12d538) (17 Aug 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 280bd44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/280bd445515acffb83231dfee79c21719ad3bc7b), 15 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### [`merge-recursive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/743474cbfa8b65016dd02b4e56dd9f47f95652c3): provide a better label for diff3 common ancestor
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> In [commit 7ca56aa07619](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ca56aa07619b0345b643e52ae8e616cbaafc187) ("`merge-recursive`: add a label for ancestor", 2010-03-20, Git v1.7.1-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16b8a3e4b94dc7f6e05b624eae3cf1eed7b358a5)), a label was added for the '`||||||`' line to make it have the more informative heading '`|||||| merged common ancestors`', with the statement:
>
> > It would be nicer to use a more informative label.
> > Perhaps someone will provide one some day.
>
> This chosen label was perfectly reasonable when recursiveness kicks in, i.e. when there are multiple merge bases.
>
> (I can't think of a better label in such cases.)
>
> But it is actually somewhat misleading when there is a unique merge base or no merge base.
>
> Change this based on the number of merge bases:
>
> ```
> >=2: "merged common ancestors"
>   1:   <abbreviated commit hash>
>   0:   "<empty tree>"
> ```
>
> Tests have also been added to check that we get the right ancestor name for each of the three cases.

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), "`git apply --3way`" learned to honor `merge.conflictStyle` configuration variable, like merges would.

See [commit 091489d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/091489d068e0e812123f5114149bdb0e7d74c257), [commit aa76ae4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa76ae4905c28e264f0affc58e36c1db692fa881), [commit 9580620](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95806205cd7013f524b6a7f10afc8542ab0c1929), [commit b006968](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0069684d430ea67fd3fbe019c71a18d4ef87fa3), [commit fa87b81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa87b813853b12fee2a931c6084134fe1eea3b55) (23 Oct 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit eff313f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eff313f8a7ff64cb3097d185c55f5ce7271f4ee9), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/091489d068e0e812123f5114149bdb0e7d74c257): respect merge.conflictStyle in --3way
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> **Before, when doing a 3-way merge, the `merge.conflictStyle` option was not respected and the "`merge`" style was always used, even if "`diff3`" was specified.**
>
> Call `git_xmerge_config()` at the end of `git_apply_config()` so that the merge.conflictStyle config is read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder why they do not set it to default in recent versions of git?

Comment: I think because of the linux origin of Git: by default, the diff from Git behaves like the linux diff.

Comment: Your first line says "from this article" but there is no link.

Comment: @Wildcard You are correct. I have added the missing link. Thank you.

Answer (score 23):

Another contender for default merge conflict style: **`zdiff3`**, starting with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022): "**Zealous `diff3`**" style of merge conflict presentation has been added.

See [commit ddfc44a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ddfc44a898a58311392a5329687a1813d6b94779) (01 Dec 2021) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 4496526](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4496526f80b3e4952036550b279eff8d1babd60a) (01 Dec 2021) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4ce498b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ce498baa3976cf96d3feb4215a486dd47ec2e7b), 15 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`xdiff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4496526f80b3e4952036550b279eff8d1babd60a): implement a zealous diff3, or "zdiff3"
>
> <sup>Based-on-patch-by: Uwe Kleine-König</sup>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> "zdiff3" is identical to ordinary `diff3` except that it allows compaction of common lines on the two sides of history at the beginning or end of the conflict hunk.
> For example, the following `diff3` conflict:
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> <<<<<<
> A
> B
> C
> D
> E
> ||||||
> 5
> 6
> ======
> A
> X
> C
> Y
> E
> >>>>>>
> 7
> 8
> 9
> ```
>
> has common lines '`A`', '`C`', and '`E`' on the two sides.
> With `zdiff3`, one would instead get the following conflict:
>
> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> A
> <<<<<<
> B
> C
> D
> ||||||
> 5
> 6
> ======
> X
> C
> Y
> >>>>>>
> E
> 7
> 8
> 9
> ```
>
> Note that the common lines, '`A`', and '`E`' were moved outside the conflict.
>
> Unlike with the two-way conflicts from the 'merge' `conflictStyle`, the `zdiff3` conflict is NOT split into multiple conflict regions to allow the common '`C`' lines to be shown outside a conflict, because `zdiff3` shows the base version too and the base version cannot be reasonably split.
>
> Note also that the removing of lines common to the two sides might make the remaining text inside the conflict region match the base text inside the conflict region (for example, if the `diff3` conflict had '`5 6 E`' on the right side of the conflict, then the common line '`E`' would be moved outside and both the base and right side's remaining conflict text would be the lines '`5`' and '`6`').
> This has the potential to surprise users and make them think there should not have been a conflict, but there definitely was a conflict and it should remain.

Answer (score 20):

`diff3` should be the default.  It is not only useful for resolving conflicts, it makes resolving conflicts *possible*. It is literally impossible to correctly resolve conflicts using (only) the default merge
conflict style. I suggest to everyone to set `diff3` in their global options.

```
git config --global merge.conflictStyle diff3
```

Why is it literally impossible?  Consider a branch which adds a
function `foo1` at a particular source file location

```py
def foo1():
    print("foo1")
```

and another branch which adds a function `foo2` at the same location

```py
def foo2():
    print("foo2")
```

If I rebase one on the other I get a conflict.  The default merge
conflict style will show

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +def foo1():
 +    print("foo1")
++=======
+ def foo2():
+     print("foo2")
++>>>>>>> Add foo2
```

What are the conflict markers telling me?  They're telling me that I
need to *add* both `foo1` and `foo2` to the file, right?
Unfortunately not!  Consider a file in which `foo1` and `foo2` already
exist, and two branches, one of which removes `foo1` and one of which
removes `foo2`.  If I rebase one on the other what is the result?  The
default merge conflict style will show

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +def foo1():
 +    print("foo1")
++=======
+ def foo2():
+     print("foo2")
++>>>>>>> Remove foo1
```

Under the default conflict style the case of removing two functions is
completely indistinguishable from the case of adding two functions
(besides the text of the commit message which can only ever be a
hint)!  Therefore it is insufficient for purpose of
resolving conflicts.  This probably explains why resolving conflicts
is seen as a dark art.  `diff3` not only makes it possible, it often makes it easy.

EDIT: here is what the `diff3`s look like in each case:

- Each `foo` added

  ```
  ++<<<<<<< HEAD
  +def foo2():
  +    print("foo2")
  ++||||||| ef9ce8d
  ++=======
  + def foo1():
  +     print("foo1")
  ++>>>>>>> a1
  ```

  You can see (from the middle section) that nothing was there before.
- Each `foo` deleted

  ```
  ++<<<<<<< HEAD
  +def foo2():
  +    print("foo2")
  ++||||||| 845b035
  + def foo1():
  +     print("foo1")
  ++
  ++def foo2():
  ++    print("foo2")
  ++=======
  ++def foo1():
  ++    print("foo1")
  ++>>>>>>> a2
  ```

  You can see (from the middle section) that both `foo`s were there before.

Comment: In a vacuum I agree that this avoids inherent (unacceptable with zero context) ambiguity, but I don't really get this argument in practice: I *know* that I deleted `foo2` in my branch, so then I delete (in the file or in my head) `foo2` from the `>>>>>>> Remove foo1` block, reassess what's left, realize that `foo1` is only in my branch but not in the branch I'm merging/rebasing, and *I didn't add* `foo1` so clearly it was removed in the other branch.

Comment: (Still a +1 to the answer, to be clear, because you have helped me understand what the fuss is about - why people like `diff3` so much, what they find difficult about the default minimal way, etc.)

Comment: Example of how it looks with `diff3` would be nice here.

Comment: Yes, fair point. Added.

Answer (score 4):

> Why it is not the default behavior of git?

I think it's not default because `git mergetool` shows 3 panels on top anyway: local, base (common ancestor) and remote + the 4th panel at the bottom, which has the content as you write in your question.

So if you turn on `diff3` and use `mergetool`, you then have information duplicated in the middle top panel and in the section between ||||||| and ======== in the bottom panel.

Answer (score 1):

While I must say that I like diff3 much, one downside is that conflicts sometimes tend to be larger then.

And of course, changing defaults for new features can confuse people.